# dynamic angular & angular includes not showing on safari browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, safari, cross-platform

angular website is not displaying at **all** on Safari browser, only.

The div background colors and height width are displaying but my templated dynamic angular content is not displaying at all.

*ie.* the below are not read in safari browser only.

```
 <div ng-include="templates.player" ng-controller="PlayerCtrl" class="music-player"></div>
```

& all areas like the below:

```
  <div ng-include="templates.welcome"></div>

  <div ng-include="templates.shareModal"></div>

  <div ng-view class="view"></div>
```

This is so bizarre to me, any pointers? *(I am also new to angular)*